# Spring Boot - Camel - Tracking an exchange all the way through

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

We are trying to setup a very simple auditing database table for a very complex Spring Boot, Camel application with many routes (mostly internal routes using seda://)...the idea being we record in the database table each route's processing outcome.  Then when issues arise we can login to the database, query the table and pinpoint exactly where the issue happened.  I thought I could just use the exchange-id as the unique tracking identifier, but quickly learned that all the seda:// routes make new exchanges, or at least that's what I'm seeing (camel version 2.24.3).  Frankly, I don't care what we use for the unique identifier...I can generate a UUID easily enough and the use the exchange.setProperty("id-unique", UUID).

I did manage to get something to work using the exchange.setProperty("id-exchange", exchange.getExchangeId()) and have it persist the unique identifier thru the routes...(I did read that certain pre-defined route prefixes such as jms:// will not persist exchange properties though).  The thought being, the very first Processor places the exchangeId (unique-id) on the exchange properties, my tracking logic is in a processor that I can include as part of the Route's definition :

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    // EVENTS : Collect statistics from Camel events
    this.getContext().getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(this.camelEventNotifier);

    // INITIAL : ${body} exchange coming from a simple URL endpoint 
    // POST request with an XML Message...simulates an MQ 
    // message from Central MQ.  The Web/UI service places the
    // message onto the camel route using producerTemplate.
    from("direct:" + Globals.ROUTEID_LBR_INTAKE_MQ)
        .routeId(Globals.ROUTEID_LBR_INTAKE_MQ)
        .description("Loss Backup Reports MQ XML inbound messages")
        .autoStartup(false)
        .process(processor)
        .process(getTrackingProcessor())
        .to("seda:" + Globals.ROUTEID_LBR_VALIDATION)
    .end();

}
```

This Proof-of-Concept (POC) allowed me to at least get things tracking like we want...note multiple rows with the same unique identifier :

```
ID_ROW  ID_EXCHANGE PROCESS_GROUP   PROCESS_STEP    RESULTS_STEP    RESULTS_MESSAGE
1   ID-LIBP45P-322256M-1603188596161-4-6    Loss Backup Reports lbr-intake-mq   add lbr-intake-mq
2   ID-LIBP45P-322256M-1603188596161-4-6    Loss Backup Reports lbr-validation  add lbr-intake-mq
```

Thing is, this POC is proving to be rigid and difficult to record outcomes such as SUCCESS versus EXCEPTION.

My question is, has anyone done anything like this?  And if so, how was it implemented?  Or is there a fancy way in Camel to handle this that I just couldn't find on the web?

My other ideas were :

- Set an old fashion Abstract TrackerProcessor class that all my tracked Processors extend.  Then just have a handful of methods in there to create, update, etc...  Each processor then just calls inherited methods to create and manage the audit entries.  The advantage here being the exchange is readily available with all the data involved to store in the database table.

```
@Component
public abstract class ProcessorAbstractTracker implements Processor {

    @Override
    abstract public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception;
    
    public void createTracker ( Exchange exchange ) {
    }

    public void updateTracker ( Exchange exchange, String theResultsMessage, String theResultsStep ) {
    }
}
```

- Set an @Autowired Bean that every tracked Camel Processor wires in and put the tracking logic in the bean.  This seems to be simple and clean.  My only concern/question here is how to scope the bean (maybe prototype)...since there would be many routes utilizing the bean concurrently, is there any chance we get mixed processing values...

```
    @Autowired
    ProcessorTracker    tracker;
```

- Other ideas?

tia, adym

Comment: You're auditing requirements are unclear. Have a look at the `intercept` pattern in Camel You can intercept every single step of your routes: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/intercept.html

Comment: Ok, will do...Sorry about the late response...getting pulled in many directions at work.